Extremely large bandwidth for kernel regression
I'm trying to fit my data with kernel regression using npreg() from package np. However, the bandwidth automatically selected seems a little bit off to me. I tried using different kernels (2nd-order Gaussian, 2nd-order Epanechnikov, 4th-order Gaussian, 4th-order Epanechnikov, uniform), different bandwidth selection methods (least squares cross-validation, expected Kullback-Leibler cross-validation), different estimators (local constant, local linear), but none of them solved the problem. They all just give me this ridiculously large bandwidth.

By the way, the data looks like this:


Can someone figure out where the problem is?

it seems like the kernel method is choosing to essentially predict a constant, indicating that it did not find any structure in your data.

However, when I run linear regression, the results are pretty significant when I controlled for individual fixed effects (hence factor(Subject) in the model). @JohnMadden
